# Next.js router.push() redirects but doesn't render page

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I'm running a Next.js app in localhost:3000 that initially redirects to a login page if there is not user data.
Initally it redirects to login page but it doesn't render and I get thrown this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Index (at _app.js:7)
    in ApolloProvider (at _app.js:6)
    in MyApp
    in ErrorBoundary (created by ReactDevOverlay)
    in ReactDevOverlay (created by Container)
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Root
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to Next.js and not sure how to deal with this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import Client from '../components/Client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { queryGetClientsVendor } from '../graphql/queries';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Index = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(queryGetClientsVendor);
  console.log(data, loading, error);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';

  if (!data.getClientsVendor) {
    return router.push('/login');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <h1 className='text-2xl text-gray-800 font-normal'>Index</h1>
        <Link href='/newclient'>
          <a className='bg-blue-800 py-2 px-5 mt-5 inline-block text-white rounded text-sm hover:bg-gray-800 mb-3 uppercase font-bold'>
            New Client
          </a>
        </Link>

        <table className='table-auto shadow-md mt-10 w-full w-lg'>
          <thead className='bg-gray-800'>
            <tr className='text-white'>
              <th className='w-1/5 py-2'>Name</th>
              <th className='w-1/5 py-2'>Company</th>
              <th className='w-1/5 py-2'>Email</th>
              <th className='w-1/5 py-2'>Delete</th>
              <th className='w-1/5 py-2'>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody className='bg-white'>
            {data.getClientsVendor.map((client) => (
              <Client key={client.id} client={client} />
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

You can also check the whole code project on github => https://github.com/francislagares/crm-react

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't return `router.push` - it not `React child`.

I suggest you try with:

```
if (!data.getClientsVendor) {
   router.push('/login');
   return <p>Redirecting...</p>;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I already tried and redirects well but when I log in it redirects to login page again. I need to redirect to admin page after login.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after digging into Next docs I finally could make it work with getInititalProps:

```
Index.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx && ctx.req) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/login' });
    ctx.res.end();
  } else {
    return {};
  }
};
```

Thanks.